# Running discard server on netty

Tags: netty

I downloaded netty from [here](http://netty.googlecode.com/files/netty-4.0.0.CR2.tar.bz2) and unzipped/untarred it.

Now, I want to run Discard Server, which is the first example in most netty tutorials.

If I unjar `netty-example-4.0.0.CR2.jar`, I can see `io/netty/example/discard/DiscardServer.class`, and I know this has main method too.

My question is: how do I run discard server?

I tried

```
java -jar netty-common-4.0.0.CR2.jar io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer
```

which yields:

> Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
>   netty-common-4.0.0.CR2.jar

I tried unjarring the jar, putting main class name as following in the manifest file:

```
Main-Class: io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer
```

Running the jar still gives me the error:

> Could not find the main class: io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer.
>   Program will exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only load the `netty-common-4.0.0.CR2.jar` in java, but the examples are in the `netty-example-4.0.0.CR2.jar` file and they depend on some of the other jar files from netty.

Therefore you must specify your classpath with the option `-cp` to use them.

```
java -cp netty-example-4.0.0.CR2.jar;netty-transport-4.0.0.CR2.jar;netty-common-4.0.0.CR2.jar;netty-buffer-4.0.0.CR2.jar io.netty.example.discard.DiscardServer
```

Hope this helps.